# Sum object key by key with Mongo on Node

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, nosql

I'm trying to group all this object in one, the idea is to combine all the object.

My function know is like this:

```
app.get('/stats/:id(\\d+)/weapon/:weapon', function(req, res, next) {
        db.collection('stats').aggregate( [
            { $match: { _id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10) } },
            { $unwind: "$session" },
            { $addFields: { weapon: { $objectToArray: '$session.weapons.' + sanitize(req.params.weapon) }, _id: false } },
            { $addFields: { weapon: { $arrayToObject: "$weapon" } } },
            { $project: { weapon: "$weapon", _id: false }  }
         ], function(err, doc) {
                if( !err ) {
                    res.json(doc);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.end();
                }
        });
    });
```

and return something like this:

```
[
   {
      "weapon":{
         "shots":30,
         "hitbox":{
            "head":7,
            "chest":4
         },
         "kills":4,
         "dmg":590
      }
   },
   {
      "weapon":{
         "shots":46,
         "kills":4,
         "hitbox":{
            "head":3,
            "chest":4,
            "stomach":3,
            "left_leg":2
         },
         "hs":3,
         "dmg":479
      }
   },
   {
      "weapon":{
         "shots":30,
         "hitbox":{
            "head":7,
            "chest":4
         },
         "kills":4,
         "dmg":590
      }
   }
]
```

My idea is to return only one instance of weapon with the sum key by key.
I already try $group and concat array but i can't get the result that i want...

I want like this:

```
[
   {
      "weapon":{
         "shots":160,
         "hitbox":{
            "head":17,
            "chest":12,
            "stomach":3,
            "left_leg":2
         },
         "kills":12,
         "hs":3,
         "dmg":1659
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample document that you are running aggregation on to the post as well ?

Comment: @Veeram https://pastebin.com/jX8iDwSt (the full document)